# Is there a way to redirect stderr to a file that works in bash, csh and dash?

Tags: c, bash, csh

How do I redirect `stderr` (or `stdout`+`stderr`) to a file if I don't know which shell (`bash`, `csh`, `dash`) is interpreting my command?

My C code running on Linux/FreeBSD/OSX needs to call an external program via the `system()` function, which will use `/bin/sh` to interpret the supplied command line. I would like to capture the messages printed by that external program to `stderr` and save them to a file. The problem is that on different systems `/bin/sh` points to different shells that have different syntax for redirecting the `stderr` stream to a file.

The closest thing I found is that bash actually understands the `csh`-style syntax for redirecting `stderr`+`stdout` to a file:

```
some_program >& output.txt
```

but `dash`, which is the default shell on Ubuntu (i.e. very common), does not understand this syntax.

Is there a syntax for `stderr` redirection that would be correctly interpreted by all common shells? Alternatively, is there a way to tell `system()` (or some other similar C function?) to use `/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `/bin/sh` to interpret the supplied command line?

Comment: I would shorten this question to "Is there a way to redirect stderr that works in csh?"  Follow the advice given below; ignore csh.

Comment: Indeed, realization that `/bin/sh` cannot point to `csh` so I should use POSIX (`bash`-like) syntax for redirection solved the problem! Thanks everyone for the detailed answers!

Comment: The example from @thatotherguy is very useful as, counter to my intuition, `system("some_program > output.txt 2>&1");` has the desired effect when `/bin/sh` points to `dash` while `system("some_program 2>&1 > output.txt");` somehow does not redirect `stderr` to the file.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, this would be a slightly different question as it would be `csh`-specific. Mine was about a portable way to redirect `stderr` and the correct answer was, indeed, to use the `bash`-like syntax and forget `csh`.

Comment: @KirillSokolovsky every time you have trouble understanding shell redirections think of them as of variable assignments, because that's how they work, basically: `>output 2>&1` is `fd1="output.txt"; fd2=fd1` and `2>&1 >output` is `fd2=fd1; fd1="output.txt"`. You won't get confused by the difference between `a = "foo"; b = a` and `b = a; a = "foo"` in C, would you? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On any POSIX-like system, you can use

```
system("some_program > output.txt 2>&1");
```

This is because POSIX `system` is [equivalent to calling `sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html), and POSIX `sh` [supports this kind of redirection](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07). This works independently of whether or not a user opening a terminal on the system will see a Csh prompt.

Answer (score 6):

You have a mistaken assumption, that `/bin/sh` can be an "alternate" shell like `csh` that's incompatible with the standard shell syntax. If you had a system setup like that, it would be unusably broken; no shell scripts would work. Pretty much all modern systems attempt to conform, at least superficially, to the POSIX standard, where the `sh` command processes the Shell Command Language specified in POSIX, which is roughly equivalent to the historical Bourne shell and which `bash`, `dash`, `ash`, etc. (shells which are commonly installed as `/bin/sh`) are all 99.9% compatible with.

You can completely ignore `csh` and similar. They're never installed as `sh`, and only folks who actually want to use them, or who get stuck using them as their interactive shell because some evil sysadmin setup the login shell defaults that way, ever have to care about them.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I redirect stderr (or stdout+stderr) to a file if I don't know which shell (bash, csh, dash) is interpreting my command?

You don't.  Bourne-family shells and csh-family shells have different, incompatible syntax for redirecting stderr.  In fact, `csh` and `tcsh` do not have a syntax to redirect only stderr at all -- they can redirect it only together with stdout.

If you really could be in any shell at all, then you're pretty much hosed with respect to doing much of anything.  One could imagine an obscure, esoteric shell with completely incompatible syntax.  For that matter, even an unusual configuration of a standard shell could trip you up -- for example if the `IFS` variable is set to an unusual value in a Bourne-family shell, then you'll have trouble executing any commands that don't take that into account.

If you can count on executing at least simple commands, then you could execute a known shell within the unknown one to process your command, but that oughtn't to be necessary for the case that seems to interest you.

> Alternatively, is there a way to tell system() (or some other similar
>   C function?) to use /usr/bin/env bash instead of /bin/sh to interpret
>   the supplied command line?

Not on a POSIX-conforming system.  POSIX specifies explicitly that the `system()` function executes the command by use of `/bin/sh -c [the_command]`.  But this *shouldn't* be something to worry about, as `/bin/sh` *should* be a conforming POSIX shell, or at least pretty close to one.  Definitely it should be a Bourne-family shell, which both `bash` and `dash` are, but `tcsh` most definitely is not.

The way to redirect the standard error stream in a POSIX shell is to use the `2>` redirection operator (which is a special case of a more general redirection feature applicable to *any* file descriptor).  Whatever shell `/bin/sh` actually is should recognize that syntax, and in particular `bash` and `dash` both do:

```
some_program 2> output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is another possibility worth mentioning: You could open the file you want to redirect on stderr in your c-code prior to calling `system()`. You can `dup()` the original stderr first, and then restore it again.

```
fflush(stderr); // Flush pending output
int saved_stderr = dup(fileno(stderr));
int fd = open("output.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0600);
dup2(fd, fileno(stderr));
close(fd);
system("some_program");
dup2(saved_stderr, fileno(stderr));
close(saved_stderr);
```

This should perform the output redirection as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the shell.... of course you don't know how to redirect from it, despite of the fact that you can see what value the `$SHELL` has, and act in consequence:

```
char *shell = getenv("SHELL");
if (*shell) { /* no SHELL variable defined */
    /* ... */
} else if (!strcmp(shell, "/bin/sh")) { /* bourne shell */
    /* ... */
} /* ... more shells */
```

Despite of what you say in your question, it is quite unusual to rename `/bin/sh` to use another shell, as shell scripts use syntax that depends on that.  The only case I know is with `bash(1)`, and I have seen this only in Linux (and remarkably, last versions of solaris), but the syntax of `bash(1)` is a superset of the syntax of `sh(1)`, making it possible to run shell scripts made for `sh(1)` with it.  Renaming `/bin/sh` to `perl` for example, would make your system probably completely unusable, as many system tools depend of `/bin/sh` to be a bourne compatible shell.

By the way, the `system(3)` library function always calls `sh(1)` as the command interpreter, so there should be no problem to use it, but there's no solution to capture the output and process it by the parent process (indeed, the parent process is the `sh(1)` that `system(3)` `fork(2)`s)

Another thing you can do is to `popen(3)` a process.  This call gives you a `FILE` pointer to a pipe of a process.  You popen its input in case you `popen(3)` it for writing, and you popen its output if you want or read its output.  Look at the manual for details, as I don't know now if it redirects only its standard output or it also redirects the standard error (I think only redirects standard output, for reasons discussed below, and only if you `popen(3)` it with a `"r"` flag).

```
FILE *f_in = popen("ps aux", "r");
/* read standard output of 'ps aux' command. */
pclose(f_in);  /* closes the descriptor and waits for the child to finish */
```

Another thing you can do is to redirect yourself after `fork(2)`ing the child, and before the `exec(2)` call  (this way you can decide if you want only `stdout` or if you want also `stderr` redirected back to you):

```
int fd[2];
int res = pipe(fd);
if (res < 0) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if ((res = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else if (res == 0) { /* child process */
    dup2(fd[1], 1); /* redirect pipe to stdout */
    dup2(fd[1], 2); /* redirect pipe also to stderr */
    close(fd[1]); close(fd[0]); /* we don't need these */
    execvp(program, argv);
    perror("execvp");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else { /* parent process */
    close(fd[1]); /* we are not going to write in the pipe */
    FILE *f_in = fdopen(fd[0]);
    /* read standard output and standard error from program from f_in FILE descriptor */
    fclose(f_in);
    wait(NULL); /* wait for child to finish */
}
```

You can see a complete example of this (not reading standard error, but it is easy to add --- you have only to add the second dup2() call from above) [here](https://github.com/mojadita/cont.git).  The program executes repeatedly a command you pass to it on the command line.  It needs to get access to the output of the subprocess to count the lines, as between invocations, the program goes up as many lines as the program output, to make the next invocation to overlap the output of the last invocation.  You can try it and play, making modifications as you like.

## NOTE

In your sample redirection, when you use `>&`, you need to add a number after the ampersand, to indicate which descriptor you are `dup()`ing.  As the number before the `>` is optional, the one after the `&` is mandatory.  So, if you have not used it, prepare to receive an error (which probably you don't see if you are redirecting `stderr`)  The idea of having two separate output descriptors is to allow you to redirect `stdout` and at the same time, conserve a channel where to put error messages.